# Override injected class in lumen test

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, mockery

I implementing rest api with lumen where I use mostly MySql procedures I have some Connection class, Repository which is injected to Controllers, but I want test these Repositories with replacing Connection class in Constructor because I use procedures I don't want any test database where will be called.

Example RepositoryClass:

```
class UserRepository {
    protected $readConnection;

    public function __construct(MydbConnection $readConnection) {
        $this->readConnection = $readConnection;
    }

    public function checkUserPermission(username, password) {
        return $this->readConnection->callProcedure('check_perm', [username, password]);
    }

}
```

in test I have:

```
class AuthTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $controller;
    protected $mockConn;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        // make mockery object
        $this->mockConn = Mockery::mock(MydbConnection::class);
        $this->app->instance(MydbConnection::class, $this->mockConn);

        // try override userRepository 
        $repo = $this->app->make(UserRepository::class);
        $this->app->bind( UserRepository::class, $repo);

        // then override controller
        $this->controller = $this->app->make(AuthController::class);
        $this->app->bind(AuthController::class, function () {
            return $this->controller;
        });
    }

    public function testLogin()
    {
       $this->post('/auth/login', [
           'username' => 'test.dev',
            'password' => 'Test123'
       ]);

        $this->mockConn->shouldReceive('callProcedure');
   }
}
```

but this is not working this way, could you help me how can I replace the MydbConnection with mockery object?